# Chrome web store : An error occurred => manifest.json:1:1: a object must begin with '{'

Tags: json, web, manifest, chrome-web-store

After uploading my web application in chrome webstore, an error appear after the upload is done. 
This is the error:

[image]

And this is my manifest.json file:

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
           "128": "icon128.png" },
```

How to fix this manifest.json?

Answer (score 0):

JSON documents always start with a open curly brace, and end in one too.

```
{
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
           "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```